# How to check for empty array (array of struct)

Tags: arrays, go

A mySQL Query function returns an array of rows witch is defined as

```
type Row []interface{}
```

I would like to check if the returned array is empty, but I get a runtime panic:

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("select id, secret, shortname from beehives where shortname = '%s'", beehive)

rows, res, err := database.Query(s)
if err == nil {
    if len(rows) != 1 {
```

The expression len(rows) seems to cause the runtime panic if rows is empty.

How can I check for an empty array? I tried also rows == nil, which also panics.

Comment: Which library is this? Because http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query returns two variables. You could check if rows.Next() returns false on the first check I suppose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you could use `QueryRow`, since that query is expected to return only one row.

> QueryRow executes a query that is expected to return at most one row. QueryRow always return a non-nil value. Errors are deferred until Row's Scan method is called.

In this case, if there is no row, the `ErrNoRows` occurs, but is deferred until a `.Scan` occurs.

> ErrNoRows is returned by Scan when QueryRow doesn't return a row. In such a case, QueryRow returns a placeholder *Row value that defers this error until a Scan.

So what you want to do is something like:

```
var id int
var secret string
var shortname string
err := db.QueryRow("SELECT ...").Scan(&id, &secret, &shortname)
switch {
    case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        log.Printf("Not found.")
    case err != nil:
        log.Fatal(err)
    default:
        //do stuff
}
```

Otherwise, since you need to be looping over `rows.Next` anyways, you can easily set a flag:

```
defer rows.Close()
has_results := false
for rows.Next() {
    has_results = true
    //do stuff
}
if (!has_results) {
    //error handling
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I changed from github.com/ziutek/mymysql package to github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql. I much happier with it.