# How come I get cannot use type *sql.Row as type error when doing err == sql.ErrNoRows

Tags: go

I was trying to follow the example in the answer given here:
[Golang: How to check for empty array (array of struct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034652/golang-how-to-check-for-empty-array-array-of-struct)

on how to check if a database return is empty

So I have this:

```
err = db.QueryRow("SELECT FROM accounts WHERE steamid=?", steamid)
switch {
        case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        case err != nil:
        default:
                //do stuff
}
```

But I get the error:

```
cannot use db.QueryRow("SELECT FROM accounts WHERE steamid=?", steamid) (type *sql.Row) as type error in assignment:
    *sql.Row does not implement error (missing Error method)
```

Not sure why it worked in his example but not when I try to implement it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've missed the `Scan` part of the example, which actually returns an error:

```
err := db.QueryRow("SELECT ...").Scan(&id, &secret, &shortname)
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh shoot. Completely overlooked that.... Thanks!! Can't accept for 7 mins but I will